# How do I figure out what dependency is missing in a Node.js project

Tags: node.js, openshift

I am trying to deploy my Node.js project to OpenShift and I get 503 when trying to view the site.

I am aware from research that this indicates a problem with my webserver project. By checking the logs, I have determined that this appears to be an issue of a missing dependency. However, the logs don't appear to tell me which one:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/lib/openshift/551c63f85973ca05430002b8/app-root/runtime/repo/server.js'
```

I have verified that every package which is "required" by my webserver is present in both the package.json file and is present in the node_modules folder.

```
{
  "name": "NekoList",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "~1.12.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "ejs": "~2.3.1",
    "express": "~4.12.4",
    "mongoose": "^4.0.3",
    "morgan": "~1.5.3",
    "node-gyp": "^2.0.1",
    "secure-random": "^1.1.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.1"
  }
}
```

When running an `npm install` or `npm update` I get no errors. I do get warnings about an unmet dependency on `debug ~2.2.0`, but I have this same warning in another project and it doesn't cause a critical failure. I have no code that uses this module. It's just there because it was part of the template.

```
minimist@0.0.8 node_modules/node-gyp/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN unmet dependency /var/lib/openshift/551c63f85973ca05430002b8/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/express/node_modules/finalhandler requires debug@'~2.2.0' but will load
npm WARN unmet dependency undefined,
npm WARN unmet dependency which is version undefined
```

Also, the project runs fine on my local development environment using the Webstorm built-in server.

I am looking to know what I might do to fix, or at least shed some light on the root of the issue.

Thanks in advance.

[Edit]
So, based on what Saba Hassan is saying, it looks like node is trying to run the nonexistant file `server.js`, instead of the entry point that I have defined, `bin/www`

So, I added a file called `server.js` with the basic example server. Openshift still cannot find the file. Same error message.
[/Edit]

[Solution]
I have concluded that the basic assumption of this question is incorrect. I endorsed an answer that explains why OpenShift is looking in the wrong place for the insertion point. However, I started this thread to figure out why I was getting a missing dependency error. Even after implementing the solution below, I still got the same error message, about missing a dependency.

The explanation is this:

For some reason, any problem with the insertion point file, or any file that it requires will throw back an error saying that the insertion point file module is missing.

I had some variable in one file that wasn't configured right for OpenShift and the most helpful error message contained in the OpenShift logs was that the root module was missing.

Conclusion "missing dependency" errors might just mean that you have some kind of logic error, somewhere in your entire project. 
[/Solution]

Comment: This is really a duplicate of your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637181/openshift-with-nodejs-isnt-respecting-the-path-to-my-server-file-in-package-jso

Comment: Please read more carefully. I addressed that concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `"scripts"` property, but on OpenShift you really should use `"main"` instead. This is because OpenShift uses [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) to start and manage your Node.js application. It looks like if you don't supply a `"main"` it defaults to `server.js`

Answer (score 4):

I think you are running `node server.js` command from wrong directory. Navigate to the directory where `server.js` file exists and then run the command.

Comment: I don't have a file called server.js

Comment: This is being run on Openshift. I do not directoy run node. It happens automatically when I push a new version of the project. The package.json file is in the root repository directory and the insertion point "./bin/www" is in the right place.

Comment: Then it seems your path to that module is not set correctly.

Comment: No, I don't agree. It seems that the path to my module is being ignored and uses ./server.js as a default. It is not looking for the actual file in the actual place. Because I have scripts > start set to ./bin/www in the package.json file, it should be looking there, but it isn't

Comment: Just for fun, I tried actually adding a server.js file in the root. It still claims that the file doesn't exist. I am 100% certain that the file is in the correct place

Comment: I have come across the same error previously. And the solution to it was that I was running `node` command in wrong place.

Comment: But this is OpenShift. I do not run the node command. I don't have the permissions. It gets run by the system, and this is the right place to put it for the system to call it