# openshift with nodejs isn't respecting the path to my server file in package.json

Tags: node.js, openshift

I have been working on a Node.js server and am now uploading it to OpenShift. I am not using the default ./server.js file, but rather, my insertion point is ./bin/www.

I have set this as the insertion file in package.json like so:

```
{
  "name": "NekoList",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./bin/www"
...
},
```

I can verify that `www` is in the `./bin` this directory, and it is a valid javascript file that functions perfectly well on my local environment.

This is according to [here](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202185854-How-can-I-run-my-own-node-js-script)

However, I can tell from my logs that OpenShift is still trying to find ./server.js

What might be going on here? What other information can I post that would be helpful?

Note: This is related to the problem in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634787/how-do-i-figure-out-what-dependency-is-missing-in-a-node-js-project/30635399?noredirect=1#comment49338179_30635399), but, when I realized the problem was not actually a dependency issue, I decided to create a new thread for the real issue.

Comment: Why didn't you add it like `node $relative_path_from_repo_dir/bin/www` instead of just `./bin/www` ?

Comment: Or maybe you should try `node $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/bin/www`.

Comment: I think `$relative_path_from_repo_dir` is just a place holder used in the solution.

Comment: $relative_path... is indeed a placeholder. I checked and it is not an OpenShift environment variable. I tried $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/bin/www. It still looks for ./server.js
One funny thing is, there actually is a ./server.js file, but it can't see it for some reason

Comment: You have committed the server.js file into the git repository containing the project right before pushing right ?

Comment: I have, and also, I have used ssh to verify that the file is indeed on the server.

Comment: This is just background info. I have another thread (referenced in question) devoted to figuring that one out. What I really want to know here is why it isn't using ./bin/www

Comment: I have added the answer with what I got. See if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `"scripts"` property, but on OpenShift you need to use `"main"` instead. This is because OpenShift uses [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) to startup and manage your Node.js application.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I think I have found the problem.

From the information you provided and the one on here : [Markers files for Node.js](https://developers.openshift.com/en/node-js-project-structure.html#markers), you will have to add the marker 'use_npm' for using the `npm start` to start the server (where it looks for the start script provided in scripts section on your package.json) instead of : `supervisor <whatever-you-gave-for-main-on-package.json`.

So you will have to add an empty file named `use_npm` under `.openshift/markers`. Then commit the changes and deploy. It should then start the server with `./bin/www` of your project and also you will still have to use `node $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/bin/www` for `start` on package.json.

Btw, you haven't given here what you gave for the main section on package.json.

Comment: I will give that a shot when I have time. I'm afraid I don't really understand a lot of what you are suggesting, but maybe it will make more sense to me when I get in there.

Comment: If you switch to "use_npm" then you won't get all the monitoring and restart-on-crash features that OpenShift provides through node-supervisor. See my answer for the correct way to specify your start script for OpenShift.